# R: Comparing Data Frames

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have 2 data frames. One contains reference data and one contains raw data.
I want to add a column to the raw data that basically says, if one of the items in the reference table exists in the raw data, flag it as 1, else leave it as zero.

The raw data contains 3 rows

```
HC
HC
HC-HY
```

The reference data contains 1 row (I have simplified this just for the question)

```
HC
```

The code should put a one in a new column for each row in the raw data as HC is in all of them,

Here is my code below, which doesn't work as it seems to be ignoring HC-HY

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Raw))
  {
  for (k in 1:nrow(RefTable))
    {
    if (=RefTable[k,1] %in% Raw[i,3]){Raw[i,4] = 1} 
    } 
}
```

Comment: please use function `?dput` to export here your two (simplified) data.frames

Comment: and maybe read again your test and explain better because it doesn't seem very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if

```
rawdata = data.frame(A=c("HC","HC","HC-HY"))
refdata = data.frame(A=c("HC"))
```

then

```
rawdata$test = as.numeric(sapply(X = strsplit(rawdata$A,split = "-",fixed = TRUE), FUN=function(x) any(x %in% refdata$A)))
```

Comment: Hi @RockScience, your method is far more elegant than all my loops but it seems to suffer the same problem, in that the "HC-HY" is set at 0 when it should be 1 because the HC is contained within the string HC-HY

Comment: as I understand the question, he needs to break down the rawdata in its components first by:

`x <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(rawdata$A), "-")))`

and then do the 

`rawdata$test = as.numeric(x %in% refdata$A)`

Comment: @JohnSmith
I updated my answer. But you should certainly precise the construction of rwa data: are the raw data always separated by "-" ? are there only pairs or also triplets (HC-HY-HB) ?

Comment: @RockScience There can be triplets too. Basically each code is representative of a different tye of monetary charge. So the more times a record gets billed for a feature, the more charges get concatenated to the string. Thank you for the answer but it appears there is an error in the code: Error in strsplit(rawdata$A, split = "-", fixed = TRUE) : 
  non-character argument

Comment: Hi @RockScience, your answer is perfect, the error is basically down to the as.character(rawdata$A). Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @JohnSmith OK. To avoid this issue with the `as.character`, you should build your data.frame by selecting `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`